# Error in latent class poisson regression using the flexmix package

Tags: r

I am attempting to perform a latent class poisson regression analysis based on the research by Decker and Trusov titled ["Estimating Aggregate Consumer Preferences from Online Product Reviews"](https://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.1670653). I'm using R and the flexmix package for this purpose.

The dataset I'm working with is stored in a CSV file named "data.csv". Here is the code I'm using:

```
library(flexmix)

data <- read.csv("data.csv")
m1 <- flexmix(
  formula = rating ~ attribute1_pos + attribute1_neg + attribute2_pos + attribute2_neg + attribute3_pos + attribute3_neg + attribute4_pos + attribute4_neg + attribute5_pos + attribute5_neg + attribute6_pos + attribute6_neg + product_2 + product_3 + product_4 + product_5,
  k = 3,
  data = data,
  model = FLXMRglm(family = 'poisson')
)
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Error in FLXfit(model = model, concomitant = concomitant, control = control,  : 
     1 Log-likelihood: NA
```

To provide some context,

1. The dependent variable in my analysis is the rating for online reviews.
2. The independent variables consist of dummy variables representing the sentiment values for each product attribute (positive, negative, and neutral). Hence, there are two dummy variables for each attribute.
3. Additionally, I have dummy variables for the five products I researched, resulting in four dummy variables.
4. The dataset comprises a total of 38,798 online reviews.

I have tried adding a maximum iteration control

```
library(flexmix)

data <- read.csv("data.csv")
m1 <- flexmix(
  formula = rating ~ topic1_pos + topic1_neg + topic2_pos + topic2_neg + topic3_pos + topic3_neg + topic4_pos + topic4_neg + topic5_pos + topic5_neg + topic6_pos + topic6_neg + brand_2 + brand_3 + brand_4 + brand_5,
  k = 3,
  data = data,
  model = FLXMRglm(family = 'poisson'),
  control = list(iter.max = 100)
)
```

However, it still gave the same error.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully execute the latent class Poisson regression analysis.

I am also open to utilizing the Python programming language to conduct the latent class Poisson regression.